# material ui [Tooltip] not been removed when the origin element had been removed

Tags: material-ui, tooltip

the code is like this:

```
<div id="rr"><Tooltip title="dd" aria-label="add">
      <div className="card_title_text" onClick={() => document.getElementById('rr').remove()}>rrrr</div>
    </Tooltip></div>
```

when click title,element removed but the global tooltip still position on the page,how to fix it?I need to remove component by using document.remove
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4IoQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make useState variable, init value is true. And when removed component, the state change false.

ex)

```
{ openTooltip && <Tooltip> ... </Tooltip> }
```

If openTooltip is true, Tooltip component is mounted.
If openTooltip is false, Tooltip component is unmounted.